# can't access extended type content

Tags: reactjs

I've created 2 interfaces that extends from a common one. In my component, I said that the props can be both type. But I try to access the content from one of the extended interface, it doesn't work.

```js
interface IDefaultPayload {
    orderTokenValue: string;
    items: IActionLineItem;
}

export interface IRefundPayload extends IDefaultPayload {
    isFullShipmentRefund: boolean;
    comment: string;
}

export interface IDuplicatePayload extends IDefaultPayload {
    notes: string;
}
 // other file

interface IFooterProps {
    payload: IRefundPayload | IDuplicatePayload;
}

const Footer = ({ payload }: IFooterProps) => {
    console.log(payload.comment) // error comment does not exist on type IDuplicatePayload
{...}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you would have to give typescript a hint to narrow down the discriminated union type, since the 'comment' field is not common to both types (IRefundPayload and IDuplicatePayload) in the union.

You can do this using the `"in"` operator, which is outlined in this example from Typescript docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing.

Specifically to your situation, it could look something like this:

```js
const Footer = ({ payload }: IFooterProps) => {

    if ("comment" in typeof payload){
       console.log(payload.comment)
       // also you should be able to access payload.isFullShipmentRefund without errors

    }
}
```

If you can afford to, you can also tack on a property such as "kind" on the payload which you can use to distinguish between different payloads, and hence the properties that should be available on them. In that case you could do this:

```js
if (payload.kind === 'refund'){
    console.log(payload.comment)
    // also you should be able to access payload.isFullShipmentRefund without errors
}
```